# ¿Por qué el canvas no se descarga correctamente?

Tags: javascript, html

El siguiente código permite descargar un canvas al hacer click en el canvas. Sin embargo, cuando hago click se descarga un archivo en formato htm, cuando debería descargarse en formato png o jpg ¿Alguna solución y por qué está ocurriendo esto?

```js
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var canvas = document.getElementById("image");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
 img.src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/bYtqbOcTYOlgc6gqZ2rwb8lptHuwlNE75zYJu6Bn076-hTmvd96HH-6v7S0YUAAJXoJN";
 img.onload = function () {
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  a.setAttribute("href",canvas.toDataURL());

}
```

```html
<a href="" download id="a">
<canvas id="image" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
</a>
```

Comment: Si lo que te interesa es el archivo físico de la imagen (entiéndase el archivo con su extensión), hace un tiempo que Google decidió no ponerlo tan fácil (antes podías por ejemplo explorar el HTML y encontrar el `src` del archivo, ahora es imposible, al menos de una manera fácil). Si realmente quieres implementar descarga de archivos o manejar las extensiones, tendrás que implementar una API de Google que te permita hacerlo con mayor facilidad, sin tener que recurrir a métodos truculentos y precarios.

Comment: Hola @Lucia. El código funciona siempre que no tomes como fuente un servidor diferente al que está utilizando tu aplicación para alojarse. De hecho, te descarga el archivo HTML porque no obtiene la URL del `canvas` por motivos de seguridad, los navegadores los bloquean. Puedes probar descargando la imagen a tu computadora y repetir el proceso. Eso es asumiendo que deseas descargar desde el `canvas` lo que hayas hechos sobre él y no descargar desde otro lugar.